# MUI TableCells are not redering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

At my wits end.  My table cells won't render.  The cells for the header are fine.  Any hints, help appreciated.  I've debugged in Firefox and all the data array of objects is there, just not displaying in the browser.

[image: Screen Shot here]

Here's the React JS code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableBody, TableCell} from '@material-ui/core';
import {Container} from "@material-ui/core";

import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core";

//Not used while troubleshooting
const usePaperStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {margin: theme.spacing(20)}
}))

const MatStatefulTable = ({data}) => {
 
  return (
    <Container maxWidth={"lg"}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {Object.keys(data[0]).map((key) =>
              <TableCell>{key}</TableCell>
            )}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.forEach((row)  => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.speed}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.desc}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.duplex}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.vlan}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.admin}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.operational}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.last_changed}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Container>
  )
}
export default MatStatefulTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

use data.map instead of data.forEach. forEach doesn't return a value, thefore doesn't return the TableRow components